# JQuery UI Tabs from Dynamically Created DIVS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I am creating an information dashboard to show the results of various actions for a web app.

I would like to show data in tables, organized by tabs, ie each tab is different category with corresponding table.  The trouble is these tabs and tables need to be created on the fly based on an ajax response.

Right now I have this skeleton for the tabs in my html:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

From my ajax request I get all of the categories and all of the data as JSON, and in javascript:

```
function(data){
    //making the tab links and content divs
    $.each(data.cat, function(){
      $('#tabs ul').append('<li><a href="#'+this.id+'">'+this.name+'</a></li>');
      $('#tabs').append('<div id="'+this.id+'"></div>');
    }
    //making the tab content
    //cycle through all results, adding each to the table in div of its category
    $.each(data.results function(){
       var selector = '#' + this.catid + ' table tbody';
       $(selector).append('<tr><td>'+this.something+'</td><td>'+ 
            this.somethingelse + '</td></tr>');
    }
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
}
```

This is "working" right now.  It appropriately puts the data into the right divs that is creating, but the styling when I call tabs() is not taking place so I just have divs underneath each other.  I know the problem -- these divs are new to the DOM and jquery isn't seeing them, but I have no idea how to fix it!

Comment: jQuery is seeing the modified DOM by the time you are calling .tabs(), if tabs is being called before you call your ajax, then using the .tabs('add'...) is the correct method to be using (see answer below). On a side note, you have some Javascript errors in your code, but it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/AcV3H/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is seeing the modified DOM by the time you are calling .tabs(), if tabs is being called before you call your ajax, then using the .tabs('add'...) is the correct method to be using (see below). On a side note, you have some Javascript errors in your code, but it does work: as you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/AcV3H

For adding new tabs, you should use the `.tabs('add' ...)` method.

> .tabs( "add" , url , label , [index] )
>
> Add a new tab. The second argument is either a URL consisting of a fragment identifier only to create an in-page tab or a full url (relative or absolute, no cross-domain support) to turn the new tab into an Ajax (remote) tab. The third is the zero-based position where to insert the new tab. Optional, by default a new tab is appended at the end.
>
> NOTE: Tabs created dynamically using .tabs( "add", ... ) are given an id of ui-tabs-NUM, where NUM is an auto-incrementing id.

So your code may look something like...

```
function(data) {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    ...
    $.each(data.cat, function() {
        $('#tabs').tabs('add', this.id, this.name);
    });
}
```

Comment: If I did that I would have to rewrite all of my ajax calls and I have other areas of that dashboard using this data so I would really not like to.  Prior to calling tabs() I have the tabs div in the exact format that jquery needs, is there no way to get jquery to recognize the new DOM elements and build it like that?

Comment: Fortunately, it should be a very easy refactoring. Using `.tabs('add' ...)` is the preferred method for creating new tabs, however jQuery is recognizing the DOM by the time you are calling tabs, so it's likely you're having a different issue (such as Javascript errors, see edited answer).